# Is it true that in the Torah the Pharaoh of the exodus is called "Pharaoh" more frequently than "the king" alone?

Tags: pharaoh, exodus

Is it true that in the Torah, Talmud, midrash, the Pharaoh of the exodus is called "Pharaoh" more frequently than "the king" alone?

Comment: Seems pretty evident to me that yes...

Comment: About 100 times as Pharaoh and 14 as king of Egypt

Comment: thanx ... I guess that is the way in oral Torah as well?